# Where Exists returning all rows

Tags: sql

My `where exists` clause isn't working.  What trivial thing am I missing?

```
select * from patient as p
where exists
(
    select p.patientid, count(*) from tblclaims as c 
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
    and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
    and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
    group by p.patientid
    having count(*)>500
)
```

patient and tblclaims are joined together by the three-field composite key as as you can see in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count(*) from tblclaims as c` is unnecessary and could be throwing the query off.

Also, you have no `WHERE` clause joining `patient p` to your `exists` clause.

Not to mention you use `p` as an alias in both the main query and the `exists` clause, which is just confusing.

You probably want something like:

```
select * from patient
where exists
(
    select p.patientid 
    from tblclaims as c 
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
        and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
        and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
    where patient.patientid = p.patientid
    group by p.patientid
    having count(*)>500
)
```

Comment: This is correct.  The lack of a correlated WHERE clause suggests that if any patient exists with > 500 incidents, then all patients will be returned.

Comment: Oops, turns out I should refresh screens I have open more often than every 14 hours :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the inner join in the sub-query at all; that is actually the cause of your extra results. You should be referencing the "p" in the outer query.

```
select * from patient as p
where exists
(
    select 1 from tblclaims as c 
    where p.patientid = c.patientid
       and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
       and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
    group by c.patientid
    having count(*)>500
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a fan of exists. Maybe you can use other functions.  Try this:

```
select * from patient as p
where patientid IN
(
    select p.patientid from tblclaims as c 
    inner join patient as p on p.patientid=c.patientid
    and p.admissiondate = c.admissiondate
    and p.dischargedate = c.dischargedate
    group by p.patientid
    having count(*)>500
)
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of exists either, but I'm going to bully my way through it.  I am familiar with `in`

Comment: What for?  The code I posted should work.  Anyway, try executing first your subquery, and see the results